# How to convert string date in BST and GMT format to SQL Server format as date type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2014

I imported a table into SQL Server 2014 and I found that the date format is in `BST` and `GST` format. I want to create a view and change the whole column to SQL Server date type to perform operations. I don't mind truncating the time section.

```
Wed Apr 07 00:00:00 BST 1943
Tue Jan 08 00:00:00 GMT 1985
```

I was able to do it in Excel with the following formula but want to do it in SQL Server:

```
=IFERROR(DATEVALUE(MID(E2,9,2)&"-"&MID(E2,5,3)&"-"&RIGHT(E2,4)), "")
```

All I am looking for is

```
1943-04-07
1985-01-08
```

Comment: `I imported a table in Sql-Server 2013`? Probably 2012

Comment: The type of the column is nvarchar at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  CONVERT(date, RIGHT(DateColumn, 4)+ '-' + RIGHT('0' + Convert(nvarchar, (Month(SUBSTRING(DateColumn, 5, 3) + '2016'))), 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(DateColumn, 9, 2))   as dob
FROM    MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that every row in the source data follows the same format.  If there are any fringe cases these will fail.

With SQL Server 2012, and higher, you have the handy [DATEFROMPARTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213228.aspx) function.  This function returns a date when passed a year, month and day.  These can be extracted with [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187748.aspx) and [RIGHT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177532.aspx) from the source string.

Extracting the month number (1~12) is achieved by building an arbitrary date string (01-*mmm*-2000).  This is cast into a date, from which the month number is extracted.  Generally speaking I would't recommend using date strings in any format other than YYYY-MM-DD.  However this avoids the use of a CTE, which OP was keen to do.

Example

```
/* Let's create some sample values to 
 * experiment with.
 */
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        DateVal VARCHAR(50) 
    )
;

INSERT INTO @Sample
    (
        DateVal
    )
VALUES
    ('Wed Apr 07 00:00:00 BST 1943'),
    ('Tue Jan 08 00:00:00 GMT 1985')
;


/* Extracting the month number is achieved by first casting the 3 character month
 * name as a full date, by appended a day and year.  Then the month number is 
 * extracted from this.
 */
SELECT
    s.DateVal,
    SUBSTRING(s.DateVal, 9, 2)                                               AS [Day],
    MONTH(CAST('01-' + SUBSTRING(s.DateVal, 5, 3) + '-2000' AS DATE))        AS [Month],
    RIGHT(s.DateVal, 4)                                                      AS [Year],

    -- Reuse the values shown above.
    DATEFROMPARTS(
        RIGHT(s.DateVal, 4), 
        MONTH(CAST('01-' + SUBSTRING(s.DateVal, 5, 3) + '-2000' AS DATE)),
        SUBSTRING(s.DateVal, 9, 2)
    )                                AS [Date]
FROM
    @Sample AS s
;
```

**EDIT:** The original solution contained a CTE, used to look up the month number from a 3 character month name.  This has been replaced.

Comment: All the rows are same but there are Null value in some rows.

Comment: Best to remove these via the WHERE Clause.  Alternatively you could use a CASE statement to only present non-nulls to the DATEFORMPARTS function.

Comment: Okay make sense. I will wait a bit for a short way of conversion because I have multiple columns in one table with similar dates.

Comment: This one looks better than the earlier one. Looking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample output doesn't match your input data. I think you meant `1985-01-08`.

For a shorter solution, you can use [CAST or CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187928.aspx) with style 107. It expects the string to be in the `Mon dd, yyyy` format:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(DateColumn, 5, 6) + ', ' + RIGHT(DateColumn, 4), 107)
FROM    MyTable
```

Comment: I fixed the expected output, thanks. Looking in to your option.

Comment: It flashes the column but then generate the error 
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 19
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
I tried where datecolumn is not null but no difference.

Comment: Replace `CONVERT` with `TRY_CONVERT` to see which row is giving you the error

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 20
'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Check your [DB compatibility level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb933794.aspx)

Comment: It might be because of Azure Sql-Server, which is very limited in features. i will try and update